# Unable to handle this Confirmation Message - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to Automate a web application , where I click on to next page and it throws a confirmation message which I could not handle it

I have used the below in my script

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 15);
    Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    alert.accept();
```

Error : Expected condition failed: waiting for alert to be present

Comment: What you trying to do - where is your code? On what web page are you trying to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
So I think when you click on next button it open a new tab and displays 
the confirmation JavaScript alert.
You can handle this for now only through Firefox geckoDriver this 
is issue with the [ChromeDriver][1]
```

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/9040

**I've tried like below, Just check it**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
driver.navigate().
to("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(". 
    (//a[contains(text(),'Try it Yourself »')])[1]"));
    Set<String> originalWindowHandles =driver.getWindowHandles();
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    Set<String> updatedWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
      for(String window: updatedWindowHandles)
      {
        if(!originalWindowHandles.contains(window)){
          driver.switchTo().window(window);
          break;
        }
      }
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      alert.accept();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur inputs .... It was a modal dialog box which i have handled wrongly...

 I have tried by adding big timeout and identified the element using xpath and it worked fine

Thanks !